# Best practice for determining the type of a protocol buffers message

Tags: protocol-buffers

I need to serialize and deserialize a sequence of protocol buffers messages to and from a byte stream.  There are a handful of predetermined message types.  What is the recommended way of encoding the type information so that my application can know which type it should be reading?

Comment: protocol buffers *are* serialized structured data.  Could you explain why you think you need to encode serialized data?

Answer (score 9):

The most common way to do this is to use a [union message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#union).

For example:

```
message AnyMessage {
    optional Message1 msg1 = 1;
    optional Message2 msg2 = 2;
    ...
}
```

Then all messages are encoded/decoded inside an `AnyMessage` container. Starting with protobuf 2.6, you can also use the `oneof` specifier which will ensure that only one of the submessages is set.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions in no particular order are:

1. Include a Field that holds the proto name / id (and give it the same field number in all proto's say 1)
2. Use [self describing message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques?hl=zh-cn) (at the bottom of the page). In this case you can either

   - include the [FileDescriptorSet](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet) as a field (in your messages)
   - In java (and some other implementations) you can write the FileDescriptor set as the first message in a delimited file.
3. Keep the proto names small and use proto-name in the File name e.g.

   **salesProto_Store001.bin**

   This has several good points:

   - It is immediate obvious what the file format is
   - You can scan shell scripts to find where the proto is used.
   - This technique can be used by itself or combined with the above 2.
   - This technique can be used for any schema based files (e.g. Cobol).

Finally the [ProtobufEditor](http://protobufeditor.sourceforge.net/)

- Supports **Self Describing** messages where

  - The File descriptor is the first message in a delimited file
  - The first field in the message
- Has a **search function** which will try an match the **fields** in a Protobuf message against known **Proto definition** files and gives you possible match's

---

**Background:**
In case you did not know, protocol buffers proto file can be converted to a [FileDescriptorSet](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet) protocol buffer message
and stored

**Self describing messagew:**

```
message SelfDescribingMessage {
  // Set of .proto files which define the type.
  required FileDescriptorSet proto_files = 1;

  // Name of the message type.  Must be defined by one of the files in
  // proto_files.
  required string type_name = 2;

  // The message data.
  required bytes message_data = 3;
}
```